# How to destroy session and log out

Tags: php

I have a login page and a main page. On the login page I am asking for Username and Password and on the main page I m displaying some values from the database. Problem is with the logout function. I am doing it like this:

**login.php Page**

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //log in code and to go to main.php
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['logstate'])) {
    session_destroy();
}

?>
```

**main.php Page**

```
<a href="login.php?logstate=logout"><img src="logout.png" id="Logout"></a>
```

Now when I click on the log out image, it ends the session, but returns me with the URL:  `xxxxx.com/login.php?logstate=logout`

I want it to return me the url: `xxxxx.com/login.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to redirect

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //log in code and to go to main.php
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['logstate'])) {
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: xxxxx.com/login.php");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this on logout

you can call the file logout.php on logout image and code is :

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location:home.php");//change the filename where you want to redirect it after logout
?>
```

OR in your way :

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['logstate']))
{
  session_destroy();
  header("Location:home.php");//change the filename where you want to redirect it after logout
}
```

See the [Session_destroy() Doc](https://www.php.net/session_destroy), Initialize  the session is necessary while destroying the session.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a redirect

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['logstate']))
{
  session_destroy();
  header( 'Location: /login.php' ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect the user after destroying the session.

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/login.php');
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it It will solve your problem:

```
 <?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
      //log in code and to go to main.php
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['logstate']))
    {
      session_destroy();
    header("location: xxxxx.com/login.php"); 
    exit();
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

make this your logout.php file and use it as a link to logout button

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location:yourlocation.php");
    exit;
    ?>
```